# Why I can only pass the first index of my Array?

Tags: c

When I pass the array using `getEnglishWord(counterLine);` `counterLine` is array. But when it goes in the `void getEnglishWord(int countLine[])` function the only passed is `countLine[0]` or the `first index` in the array `countLine[]`.

**CODE**

```
if (countWords == countWordsInput + 1)
                        {
                            fclose(fpB);
                            getEnglishWord(counterLine);
                        }
```

**Code in void getEnglishWord(int counterLine[])**:

```
int c;
        int countLine = 0, countWords = 0, countLetters = 0;
        char translatedWords[words][letters];
        int indexCount = 0;
        c = getc(fpE);

        for (int y = 0; y < words; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < letters; x++)
                translatedWords[y][x] = NULL;
        }
        while (c != EOF)
        {
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                if (countLine == counterLine[indexCount])
                {
                    translatedWords[countWords][countLetters] = c;
                    countLetters++;
                }
                indexCount++;
                countLine++;
            }

            c = getc(fpE);
        }
        fclose(fpE);
        _getch();
```

Comment: `countLine[0]` is not the "first index", it's the value at index `0`. When an array is passed to a function, it's implicitly converted to a pointer.

Comment: try checking value of countLine[1] too

Comment: Can you show some code that illustrates what you're trying to do and what it's doing that you don't expect?

Comment: maybe you are talking about what the debugger shows. The debugger is not aware of the size of array and assumes it only has one element. You can manually inspect other elements of array.

Comment: yes Sam the debugger shows `countLine{2}` instead of `countLine{2, 0, 3}`

Comment: @dbush i updated my question sir with codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here is working:

```
void getEnglishWord ( int *counterLine, size_t counterLineSize )
{
  ...
  if ( i < counterLineSize )
    do_something_with( counterLine[i] );
  ...
}

size_t numElements = ...; // see below
getEnglishWord( counterLine, numElements );
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration.

Array objects themselves are *not* pointers; they do not *store* a pointer value.

So, when you call

```
getEnglishWord(counterLine);
```

the *expression* (*not the object!*) `counterLine` is converted from type "N-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of `counterLine` (`&counterLine[0]`).

In the function prototype

```
void getEnglishWord(int counterLine[])
```

the declaration `int counterLine[]` is treated as though it had been written `int *counterLine`; IOW, `counterLine` is declared to be a pointer to `int`, not an array of `int` (this is *only* true for function parameter declarations).

So all your function can ever receive is a pointer to the first element of the array.  However, you can still use the `[]` subscript operator on pointer values (in fact, it's *defined* in terms of pointer operations, but we don't need to get into that now).  You can still access all the elements of `counterLine` from your function, you just need to make sure you don't try to access elements past the end of `counterLine`.  It's usually a good idea to pass the array size as a separate parameter with the array:

```
void getEnglishWord ( int *counterLine, size_t counterLineSize )
{
  ...
  if ( i < counterLineSize )
    do_something_with( counterLine[i] );
  ...
}

size_t numElements = ...; // see below
getEnglishWord( counterLine, numElements );
```

There are several ways to determine the size of an array.  You can use the `sizeof` operator on the array itself, giving the total number of bytes in the array, and dividing that by the number of bytes in a single array element:

```
int counterLine[N];
size_t numElements = sizeof counterLine / sizeof counterLine[0];
```

This only works for array expressions, though; you can't use this on pointers that point to the first element of an array.  You'll just get the size of the pointer divided by the size of the element, which won't give you what you want.

Otherwise, just pass `N`:

```
getEnglishWord( counterLine, N );
```